# How to get polygon faces from CGAL convex hull

Tags: cgal, convex-hull

I use the 3D convex hull estimator implementation in `CGAL` to compute the convex polyhedron of a set of points. below shows the code:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/point_generators_3.h>
#include <CGAL/algorithm.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/convex_hull_3.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point_3;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron;
typedef Polyhedron::Facet_iterator Facet_iterator;
typedef Polyhedron::Halfedge_around_facet_circulator Halfedge_facet_circulator;

int main()
{
  std::vector<Point_3> points;

  points.push_back(Point_3(2.0f, 3.535533905932738f, 3.535533905932737f));
  points.push_back(Point_3(4.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f));
  points.push_back(Point_3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f));
  points.push_back(Point_3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
  points.push_back(Point_3(4.0f, 1.414213562373095f, 1.414213562373095f));
  points.push_back(Point_3(0.0f, 1.414213562373095f, 1.414213562373095f));
  points.push_back(Point_3(3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
  points.push_back(Point_3(2.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f));

  Polyhedron P;

  CGAL::convex_hull_3(points.begin(), points.end(), P);

  std::cout << "- Number of vertices  = " << P.size_of_vertices()    << std::endl;
  std::cout << "- Number of edges     = " << P.size_of_halfedges()/2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "- Number of faces     = " << P.size_of_facets()      << std::endl;

  for ( Facet_iterator i = P.facets_begin(); i != P.facets_end(); ++i)
  {
    Halfedge_facet_circulator j = i->facet_begin();
    CGAL_assertion( CGAL::circulator_size(j) >= 3);
    std::cout << CGAL::circulator_size(j) << ' ';
    do{
      std::cout << ' ' << std::distance(P.vertices_begin(), j->vertex());
    }while ( ++j != i->facet_begin());

    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, the output is a triangulation of faces of the polyhedron:
[image]

Is there a way to force `CGAL` to represent a face with a polygon not a set of triangles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it out-of-the box. You need to test for each edge whether the four points are coplanar.

Comment: Is this still true (july 2017)? If so this is a shame, and will make me drop CGAL convex hull in favor of QHull library... :(

Comment: CGAL is an open source project. You are welcome to submit a [pull request](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pulls). You can also open an [issue](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues) than other developer might implement if there is enough interest.

Comment: Sure. The point is that I don't see why this is not implemented already, it should have been very easy for whoever implemented/maintained the convex hull code in the first place. On the other hand you are right: maybe there is not enough interest...

Comment: It's due to a constraint with the underlying structure used to store the convex hull. This should be done while exporting the result into a face graph model.

Comment: Yes, that was my first guess but as far I know this is not done in the export method? I was expected precisely that kind of behavior in the export method.